# Python - Cannot import even when in correct directory

Tags: python

I am having an issue trying to run this code https://github.com/google/e3d_lstm.
I followed the instructions to cd into the directory then run

```
python -u run.py \
    --is_training True \
    --dataset_name mnist \
    --train_data_paths ~/data/moving-mnist-example/moving-mnist-train.npz \
    --valid_data_paths ~/data/moving-mnist-example/moving-mnist-valid.npz \
    --pretrained_model pretrain_model/moving_mnist_e3d_lstm/model.ckpt-80000 \
    --save_dir checkpoints/_mnist_e3d_lstm \
    --gen_frm_dir results/_mnist_e3d_lstm \
    --model_name e3d_lstm \
    --allow_gpu_growth True \
    --img_channel 1 \
    --img_width 64 \
    --input_length 10 \
    --total_length 20 \
    --filter_size 5 \
    --num_hidden 64,64,64,64 \
    --patch_size 4 \
    --layer_norm True \
    --sampling_stop_iter 50000 \
    --sampling_start_value 1.0 \
    --sampling_delta_per_iter 0.00002 \
    --lr 0.001 \
    --batch_size 4 \
    --max_iterations 1 \
    --display_interval 1 \
    --test_interval 1 \
    --snapshot_interval 10000
```

but immediately get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 22, in <module>
    from src.data_provider import datasets_factory
ImportError: No module named data_provider
```

I am on Linux using Python 2.7 and am in the correct directory so I don't understand why python cannot import the folder? I have also tried adding a `__init__.py` file inside of the src folder but I am still unable to import.

Here are my PYTHONPATHS

> ['', '/home/kong/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python27.zip',
>   '/home/kong/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python2.7',
>   '/home/kong/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
>   '/home/kong/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>   '/home/kong/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>   '/home/kong/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/home/kong/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
>   '/home/kong/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

However, shouldn't the path where I executed the script be automatically added into the list of locations Python searches for modules?

Comment: It might be the use of PYTHONPATH. Can you share the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: did you run your command from root directory of the repo ?

Comment: @AnandSai I have updated the post with the PYTHONPATHS.

Comment: @kederrac yes I ran the command from the root directory of the repo because run.py is in the root directory.

Comment: I had to add `__init__.py` in folder `src/data_provider`

Comment: I had to add `__init__.py` also in other subfolders in `src/`

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in the package and you might as well report it.

Comment: @furas thank you.. that did it.. It was probably supposed to be run using python 3 and not 2 if without the init files